# How can I start an X-Server via SSH in Arch Linux ARM in order to run a VNC Server?

Tags: vnc, archlinux, xorg

Hello RPi SE community,

I followed this post (i.a.) from the official forum to install an X server on my Raspberry Pi Arch Linux:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=26398

```
$ pacman -Syu
$ pacman -S xorg-server
$ pacman -S xf86-video-fbdev xf86-video-vesa
$ pacman -S xfce4
$ pacman -S x11vnc
```

This installs me the server, drivers and a desktop environment, that worked.

Then I tried different things for starting the server:

- Creating  an `.xinitrc` file
- `startxfce4` (as service, with `disown`, etc.)
- ...

However, any command that I tried with `x11vnc` failed.

```
$ x11vnc -usepw -forever -display :0
```

> 07/07/2021 13:14:29 -usepw: found
> /home/h0ch5tr4355/.vnc/passwd 07/07/2021 13:14:29 x11vnc version:
> 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05  pid: 58024 07/07/2021 13:14:29 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed. 07/07/2021 13:14:29 Trying again with
> XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
>
> 07/07/2021 13:14:29 *************************************** 07/07/2021
> 13:14:29 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:0)
>
> *** x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":0", it cannot continue.
> *** There may be "Xlib:" error messages above with details about the failure.
>
> Some tips and guidelines:
>
> ** An X server (the one you wish to view) must be running before x11vnc is    started: x11vnc does not start the X server.  (however,
> see the -create    option if that is what you really want).
>
> ** You must use -display , -OR- set and export your $DISPLAY    environment variable to refer to the display of the desired X server.
>
> - Usually the display is simply ":0" (in fact x11vnc uses this if you forget    to specify it), but in some multi-user situations it could
>   be ":1", ":2",    or even ":137".  Ask your administrator or a guru if
>   you are having    difficulty determining what your X DISPLAY is.
>
> ** Next, you need to have sufficient permissions (Xauthority)     to connect to the X DISPLAY.   Here are some Tips:
>
> - Often, you just need to run x11vnc as the user logged into the X session.    So make sure to be that user when you type x11vnc.
> - Being root is usually not enough because the incorrect MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE    file may be accessed.  The cookie file contains
>   the secret key that    allows x11vnc to connect to the desired X
>   DISPLAY.
> - You can explicitly indicate which MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE file should be used    by the -auth option, e.g.:
>   x11vnc -auth /home/someuser/.Xauthority -display :0
>   x11vnc -auth /tmp/.gdmzndVlR -display :0    you must have read permission for the auth file.    See also '-auth guess' and
>   '-findauth' discussed below.
>
> ** If NO ONE is logged into an X session yet, but there is a greeter login    program like "gdm", "kdm", "xdm", or "dtlogin" running, you
> will need    to find and use the raw display manager MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE
> file.    Some examples for various display managers:
>
> ```
>  gdm:     -auth /var/gdm/:0.Xauth
>           -auth /var/lib/gdm/:0.Xauth
>  kdm:     -auth /var/lib/kdm/A:0-crWk72
>           -auth /var/run/xauth/A:0-crWk72
>  xdm:     -auth /var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/A:0-XQvaJk
>  dtlogin: -auth /var/dt/A:0-UgaaXa
> ```
>
> Sometimes the command "ps wwwwaux | grep auth" can reveal the file
> location.
>
> Starting with x11vnc 0.9.9 you can have it try to guess by using:
>
> ```
>           -auth guess
> ```
>
> (see also the x11vnc -findauth option.)
>
> Only root will have read permission for the file, and so x11vnc
> must be run    as root (or copy it).  The random characters in the
> filenames will of course    change and the directory the cookie file
> resides in is system dependent.
>
> See also: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html

Now my questions is if anybody can provide a clean solution for running a VNC Server on a Raspberry Pi with Arch Linux, that is only accessible via SSH. (The programs, that I have installed are no requirements. Feel free to call any other software. Thanks in advance.)

Comment: I haven't used Arch Linux so far but it seems to be an issue with selecting the correct DISPLAY for output. What `ssh` command do you use?

Comment: Just `ssh user@alarm`. Do I have to use `-x` even to start an Xserver remotely?

Comment: Where is the display connected? At the remote RasPi `alarm`?

Comment: I have no display, just a VNC server.

Comment: An X-Server is used to manage input/output to/from keyboard/mouse/display. Where is the X-Server running and what display does it manage?

Comment: I think it doesn't run at all. Because I think that is the crucial problem, that I don't know how to start it properly via ssh.

Comment: If you like to get help please answer my question so I can get an idea what you are trying to do. If there is no display on `alarm` then it is no need to run an X-Server there and it doesn't make sense to ssh to it and try to start it.

Comment: I need it for VNC, too. There is no displaz attached physically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127362/discussion-between-ingo-and-h0ch5tr4355).